# Is there a way to access the roles specified in @Secured?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

We're using Spring Security to secure our controller methods.  Let's say I've got a controller that allows me to edit Foo.

```
@Controller
@Secured({"FOO_ADMINISTRATOR"})
public class FooEditorController {
...
}
```

Now I need to add a menu to my UI that let's the user access the Foo Editor.  But I only want to present that menu option to users with permission to access the FooEditorController.  Further, I would like to keep the information in exactly one place if possible.  That is, when I specify that the menu option for the Foo Editor is limited to those with the FOO_ADMINISTRATOR role, I'd like to simply query the FooEditorController and ask it what roles are required.  That way, this information is defined in one place.

(I've tried creating arrays of roles and using those in both places, but the @Secured annotation doesn't allow this.  @Secured requires an array initializer.)

Or perhaps there's a much better way of tackling this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access the roles specified in a `@Secured` annotation (or values specified in any annotation for that matter), you can use reflection to achieve that:

```
String[] roles = FooEditorController.class.getAnnotation(Secured.class).value();
```